# urlencoding in Dart

Tags: urlencode, dart

Is there a function to do urlencoding in Dart? I am doing a AJAX call using XMLHttpRequest object and I need the url to be url encoded.

I did a search on dartlang.org, but it didn't turn up any results.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Update**: There is now support for encode/decode URI in [the Dart Uri class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html)

Dart's URI code is placed in a separate library called [dart:uri](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) (so it can be shared between both `dart:html` and `dart:io`). It looks like it currently does not include a `urlencode` function so your best alternative, for now, is probably to use [this](http://neil.fraser.name/news/2011/EncodeDecode.dart) Dart implementation of JavaScript's `encodeUriComponent`.

Comment: I think I can live with it for now. But it would be nice if this get's added to dart:uri.

Comment: @Sudar agree i'll try to make some noise to get it in

Comment: dart:uri has been removed, it's now part of core. https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/pHyoawHOhU0

Comment: A link to documentation in core: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.16.0/dart-core/Uri-class.html

Comment: maybe worth putting an example right in the answer? like `Uri.encodeComponent(url);`

Answer (score 92):

```
var uri = 'http://example.org/api?foo=some message';
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(uri);
assert(encoded == 'http://example.org/api?foo=some%20message');

var decoded = Uri.decodeFull(encoded);
assert(uri == decoded);
```

http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-uri

Comment: Getting error - Illegal percent encoding in URI

Answer (score 31):

```
Uri.encodeComponent(url); // To encode url
Uri.decodeComponent(encodedUrl); // To decode url
```

Answer (score 27):

I wrote this small function to convert a Map into a URL encoded string, which may be what you're looking for.

```
String encodeMap(Map data) {
  return data.keys.map((key) => "${Uri.encodeComponent(key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(data[key])}").join("&");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont' think there is yet.    Check out http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2011/11/oauth20-and-jsonp-with-dartin-web.html and the encodeComponent method.

Note, it's lacking some characters too, it needs to be expanded.   Dart really should have this built in and easy to get to.   It may have it in fact, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Safe Url Encoding in flutter
Ex.

```
String url  = 'http://example.org/';
String postDataKey = "requestParam="
String postData = 'hdfhghdf+fdfbjdfjjndf'
```

In Case of get request :

```
Uri.encodeComponent(url+postDataKey+postData);
```

In Case of Post Data Request use **[flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)** library

```
var data = postDataKey + Uri.encodeComponent(postData);
webViewController.postUrl(url: Uri.parse(url), postData: utf8.encode(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.encodeComponent()` is correct, `Uri.encodeFull()` has a bug, see below example:

```
void main() {
  print('$text\n');
  var coded = Uri.encodeFull(text);
  print(coded);
  print('\n');
  coded = Uri.encodeComponent(text);
  print(coded);
  
}

var text = '#2020-02-29T142022Z_1523651918_RC2EAF9OOHDB_RT.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me well. Build an Uri, pass the Map onto the queryParameters. Get the encoded data by

```dart
Uri(queryParameters: <Map data>).query;
```

eg:

```dart
Uri(queryParameters: {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2}).query;
```