# Urlencode deep in dart

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, httprequest, urlencode

I've similar question like [Urlencoding in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247073/urlencoding-in-dart/17407240#17407240). I can encode Map, by HttpRequest.postFormData. But JQuery post method can encode `Map<String, dynamic>.` JQuery example:

```
$.post("controller", 
{actualTime: 1357089552, events: [{priceInsert: 1.32128, priceExecution: 1.32128}]},
function(data) {/*handle*/});
```

Firebug HttpRequest post view:

```
actualTime                  1357089552
events[0][priceExecution]   1.32128
events[0][priceInsert]      1.32128
```

Payload source is:

```
actualTime=1357089552&events%5B0%5D%5BpriceInsert%5D=1.32128&events%5B0%5D%5BpriceExecution%5D=1.32128
```

Dart can't do it easily. Someone has this problem solved?

PHP with nette requires to set some header:

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's as unclear as before.
This text ` I can encode Map, by HttpRequest.postFormData. But JQuery post method can encode Map<String, dynamic>` doesn't make sense to me at all. If you can encode Map, by HttpRequest.postFormData what **does not** work?

Comment: PostFormData requires Map<String, String>. I cannot use json-like object as data argument. Map<String, Map> or Map<String, List> throws an error.

Comment: And what about `Map<String, dynamic>` (it's equivalent with `Map` AFAIK)

Comment: I'm porting application from javascript. I would like to keep server-side unchanged. So dynamic in this context is json-> Number || List || bool || String || Map.

Answer (score 0):

I've some dirty quick fix. Not complete, not tested, working for me:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> data = {"actualTime": 1357089552, "events": [{"priceInsert": 1.32128, "priceExecution": 1.32128}]};
StringBuffer urlData = new StringBuffer("");
bool first = true;
void urlEncode(dynamic sub, String path){
    if(sub is List){
      for(int i = 0;i<sub.length;i++){
        urlEncode(sub[i], "$path%5B$i%5D");
      }
    }else if(sub is Map){
      sub.forEach((k,v){
        if(path == ""){
          urlEncode(v, "${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(k)}");
        }else{
          urlEncode(v, "$path%5B${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(k)}%5D");
        }
      });
    }else{
      if(!first){
        urlData.write("&");
      }
      first = false;
      urlData.write("$path=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(sub.toString())}");
    }
}
urlEncode(data, "");

HttpRequest xhr = new HttpRequest();
  xhr
    ..open('POST', url)
    ..onLoadEnd.listen((ProgressEvent event){/*handle success*/}, onError: (){/*handle error*/})
    ..setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    ..setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    ..send(urlData.toString());
```