# Dart Date String Formatting

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to format a date in Google Dart but cannot seem to come up with the appropriate string to match what should be in a url to pass parameters in. I'm inputting the date from an HTML control.  I tried looking at this post but didn't have much success: [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart) ;  Please let me know if you need more information.

HTML:

```
Start Date: <input type="date" id="start" name="start">
```

Dart:

```
String query="?afterTime="+startDate.valueAsDate+"&beforeTime="+endDate.valueAsDate;
```

The date comes out as:

```
2014-07-16 00:00:00.000Z
```

and I need something like this formatting:

```
2014-05-28+0%3A00%3A00
```

and/or

```
2014-05-28+0%3A00%3A00
```

Comment: I think you need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247073/urlencoding-in-dart Please add a comment whether this is what you are looking for.