# Flutter Image not loading from network url

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I'm newbie in flutter and facing issue while loading image through URL.

Image URL in my project is like this

> 10.20.3.169\uploads/room/1494073006dz15k9b.jpg

As you can see the URL slashes are not correct. When I put that url in browser, It automatically correct the url and load the image.
But [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) library not loading the image.

For testing purpose I correct the URl to

> 10.20.3.169/uploads/room/1494073006dz15k9b.jpg

Now `CachedNetworkImage` is working fine.

Do I need to encode URL before loading image ?
if **Yes** then how can I achieve it ?

Please help me in this.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247073/urlencoding-in-dart

Comment: That the browser autocorrects the URL doesn't mean this is specified by any related standard. Just use correct URLs and you should be fine.

Comment: After correcting API URL and adding http:// its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Günter Zöchbauer said after correcting API URL, and adding `http://` its working fine.
Web browser corrects the url automatically but for `CachedNetworkImage` we need to pass exact URL.
If we pass URL without http:// then library tried to pick image from file and give exception.